# When you have 5 instead of 4, what's the word instead of "quadrant"?

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers

...or, to phrase it differently, like one of those silly SAT questions... please help me fill in this blank:

**4 is to 5 as "quadrant" is to ????**

(Does that make sense?)

Comment: What is a SAT question? Anyway, tell us the context where you would use the "5" instead of quadrant.

Comment: It makes sense that you would not be familiar with this, @Alenanno, but he's talking about the analogies section of the test formerly known as the Scholastic Aptitude Test (SAT I), that commonly used as a required entrance exam for entrance into university in the United States.

Comment: Yes-- what Billare said, exactly. The context is something like "Which quadrant of the map are you targeting?" -- except there's 5 sections of the map.

Comment: This is a very poor question as "quadrant" has several meanings. I suspect that the questioner is looking for **pentagon** (or the rarer *pentangle*).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Though a very rare word, that would be a [**quintant**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quintant).

Comment: I thought about it... OED says it's obsolete, no wonder I couldn't found it anywhere...  :D

Comment: @Alenanno However obsolete, a quintant is a navigational device. Similar to a sextant or an octant, a quintant has a length that is 1/5 of a 360° circle, and is divided into five 72° sections.

Comment: Yes I "knew" it was the fifth part of a circle, when reading the "quadrant" definition, but I wasn't aware there a word for it...

Answer (score 10):

Though "quintant" seems more correct to me for English Language, in practical English Usage the answer is, surprisingly, **quadrant**.

For example, the city of [Portland](https://xray.fm/shows/quadrants), Oregon, US, is divided into five parts that they [still call](https://www.travelportland.com/itinerary/get-north/) "quadrants:"

[image]

Folks in the city of Richmond, Virginia, USA also refers to [five quadrants](http://richmondsmallbusinessassociation.com/page_quad_map.html) when discussing [results of a poll](http://richmondsmallbusinessassociation.com/page_Poll%20-%202014%20Dec.html) by a small business association:
[image: Richmond quadrants]

Extending beyond the map example OP asked about, a company called JDA also [announces](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jda-leader-all-five-gartner-supply-chain-magic-quadrants-amith-varma) and [reports](http://now.jda.com/2016-Gartner-Magic-Quadrants.html?utm_source=JDAWebsiteHomeBanner) itself as "the only company recognized as a leader in ALL FIVE Gartner Supply Chain Magic Quadrants!"
[image: Five Gartner quadrants]

Finally, looking at [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five%20quadrants%2Cquintants%2CQuintants&year_start=1955&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfive%20quadrants%3B%2Cc0), "quintants" is not found in use (in Google's English corpus) even going [back to 1800](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five%20quadrants%2Cquintants%2CQuintants&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfive%20quadrants%3B%2Cc0) while "five quadrants" is more common, not even counting instances where there are descriptive words between the two terms:
[image: Ngrams result]

Comment: Is this not just a modern malapropism of the word *quadrant*? It has fallen in to the vernacular while *quintant* (and perhaps its equivalents) hasn't; while your evidence is admirable, surely they are all instances of the word being forced into a situation for which it was not originally designed? On the other hand, of course, this is how language evolves, who am I to try and stop it…

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey It was a surprise to me too...but this is about English usage in practice documenting what is rather than what we might think "should be."

Comment: I would never use this, but +1 for a well-researched and presented answer.

Comment: *Quadrant* is close to *quarter* (the French *quartier* is also used in English in this sense) which is used to mean *area*. For example *Latin quarter*. Given this closeness it's perhaps not surprising that *quadrant* can mean *area*