# On quadrants, quintants, sextants, octants, nonants, etc

Tags: numbers, latin, prefixes

I have searched the internet for how to form the following words, but have been unable to find an authoritative source. They are obviously formed with latinate prefixes, but if you look at the lists [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix), the sandhi/morphotactics are not straightforward.

With regard to words describing equally divided parts of a plane, how are the following words formed, and do I even have them right?

```
4 - quadrant
5 - quintant
6 - sextant
7 - septant                               ???
8 - octant
9 - nonant
10 - decant/decimant                      ???
16 - sedecimant                           ???
64 - sexagesim quadrant                   ???
100 - centant/centasimant                 ???
400 - quadringentant/quadringentesimant   ???
```

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Hugely related: [Words beyond *quadrant*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20124/when-you-have-5-instead-of-4-whats-the-word-instead-of-quadrant)

Comment: Maybe you'll find better answers in [math.se] Stack Exchange, under the tag [_terminology_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

Comment: @marcellothearcane If you can direct me to commonly-available references on the topic, I would be grateful.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Perhaps "quadrant" is it. ;-)

Comment: NVZ and AndrewLeach have...

Comment: Since OED says that 'quintant' is obsolete (see the linked thread), I wouldn't hold out much hope for many others being acceptable words.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question, and I'd sure like to see an answer.

Comment: I propose either using `n-multiant` (preferred) or `n-fraction` to describe an n-divisions.

Comment: I'd love to have known the answer to this question for the case of 16. Realise that this question comes up top of results in Google when searching.